# Success and error callbacks in model.save() are random/asynchronous

Tags: jquery, post, backbone.js, asynchronous, callback

I know there are many questions already present on this topic, but none of the answers have worked for me yet. Please be a bit patient and have a look at my scenario.

I'm saving my backbone model using backbone's `model.save()` function on click event of a button.

My objective is to perform certain operation based on the response returned, once the model is saved successfully, like so:

```
SaveActivity: function( e ) 
{
    this.model.set({'value': 0});

    this.model.save(null, /* or {} - no difference with any of the two*/
    {
      success: function (model, response) 
      {
        var id = null;
        var stringed = JSON.stringify(model);
            /*   perform operation with stringed  */
      },
      error: function (model, response) 
      {
        //i am in error
      }
    });
   alert("Done");   //This is the alert mentioned below
}
```

I see a very weird behavior of the callback functions in this code. If I remove alert, then the error callback is fired (always). On the other hand, with this alert, what happens is - as soon as the button is clicked, "POST" request is fired for the model to be saved and then the alert is popped, irrespective of the fact that "save" is to be completed.

Now comes the catch - If I select "OK" on the alert box, before I have received a "200 OK" http response for the post request (verified through console again), then the error callback is fired. If I wait for "200 OK" to come for POST before selecting the alert box, then success callback is fired. But the problem is, the model is getting saved in both the cases - whether I wait for 200 OK http response to come for POST or not. Also, the POST request takes a few seconds in returning the success response.

I realize that this is because of the asynchronous behavior of the `save()` function. But I have tried many things and still problem persists. Any help in this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Here is the original code for this function

```
SaveDraftActivity: function( e ) 
{
    if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData() == '')
    {
        alert('Activity Content cannot be left blank. Please fill the content before saving.'); 
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
         this.model.set({'publishStatus' : 0});

         this.model.save({}, 
         {
                success: function (model, response) 
                {
                    var id = null;
                    var stringed = JSON.stringify(model);
                    console.log("in success ");
                    var words = stringed.split(",");
                    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (words[i].indexOf('tenantActivityId') != -1)
                        {
                            j = words[i].indexOf(":");
                            j+=2;
                            id = words[i].substring(j, words[i].length-1);
                            //break;
                        }
                    }
                    var tenantActivityId = id;

                    if (tenantActivityId != "")
                        document.getElementById("formAttachment").submit();    //Another POST Request
                    else
                         document.getElementById("RedirectForm").submit();    //Another POST Request
                },
                error: function (model, response) 
                {
                    console.log("in error ");
                }
         });
    }
    alert("Activity is successfully saved.");           
},
```

Comment: First step: you have a closing bracket too many.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake while pasting the code here (brackets are correct in the actual code). I edited the code here.

Comment: @GijsjanB - It would be great if you could help me out with the problem too...!!!

Comment: I have no idea why the behaviour of your script would change depending on when you click 'OK' on the alert. My question would be, why would you put an alert there? Why not inform the user that the model is being saved and when it is done, show the alert (or some other, more modern, way of communicating with the user). :)

Comment: PS. There are still some typo's in your code. The success and error callback should be seperated by a comma. SaveActivity is a function and should not be closed by parenthesis. The parenthesis is part of model.save. Alert can not be inside model.save. Use jshint or jslint to catch these sort of errors.

Comment: Sorry for the typo's again. Actually SaveActivity  is a very long function, so I made a lot of mistakes while copying just the required part here. The original code again has all the syntax perfect.

Comment: About the alert, as I mentioned in my problem - if I remove the alert, then always the error callback is fired (because it doesn't wait for the server to respond). I think that with alert, the asynchronous save method gets enough time to complete the POST and get a response from the server (the case when I wait for the response and then click on OK). I think implementing the sync method in my code could be an answer to this problem, but I'm not sure how to do that!!

Comment: The callbacks will be executed when you get a response from the server, never before. The only thing I see that could cause the problem is that you're making other calls to the server after this request. The `alert` cant change anything with such little code. It can however block further requests to be made, thus the change of behavior regarding when you click on the alert.

Comment: @Loamhoof - Thanks for your response, I have pasted the original code (still have skipped a few lines, as its a long implementation), for your reference.
I know that ideally callbacks should not be executed before the response from server, but in my case, the page starts to reload as soon as the model.save is encountered and POST request is sent to the server. Because of the reloading, it doesn't wait for the actual response from the server and just goes into "error" block - although it is a successful save. If there is a way in which I can stop the automatic reload, that could be helpful too.

Comment: The code inside your callbacks won't help, as your problem happens **before** those are executed. Don't you have any code executed after your `alert` line?

Comment: No, there is no code after alert line. I need to parse the response from server after the save is performed and use it to perform the next operation, which can't be done after the alert as the code there would again be executed asynchronously.